# Convert IFormFileCollection to List<IFormFile> .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .NET Core Web API project with one API query that accept form files.
So, I want to convert `Request.Form.Files` to `List<IFormFile>` for further using in service (just to notice I don't know name of files).
I want to do something like this:

```
var files = new List<IFormFile>();
files = Request.Form.Files;
service.Save(files);
```

Can I implement that? And if yes how can I implement that? Or maybe there is no ways and I need to use `IFormFileCollection` in my service?

Comment: `IFormFileCollection` implements `IEnumerable<IFormFile>`, have you just tried to use `ToList()` method, for example? e.g. `files = Request.Form.Files.ToList()`

Comment: Instead of going through `Request.Form.Files`, the recommended approach would be to simply include a list of `IFormFile`s in your POST model that gets passed to your controller action or Razor page handler.