# Convert IList<IFormFile> to IFormFileCollection .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i get data into Ilist then i want to convert it into IFormFileCollection beacause i upload data in the wwwroot folder  and also into database sql so any way to convert the data or any to use directly IList
Controller:

```
public IActionResult aprent([Bind] RentModel ar )
        
        {
            
            
            try
            {
                
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if(ar.imge1 != null && ar.imge1.Count>0)
            {
                        string folder = "image/";
                        foreach (IFormFile imge in ar.imge1)
                        {
                            folder += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + imge.FileName;




                            ar.pic1 = "/" + folder;

                            string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                            imge.CopyTo(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
                        }

                    }
```

model:

```
public IList<IFormFile>? imge1 { get; set; }
```

i cannot use any other type beacuse data cannot come into any other type.

Comment: You can try to  refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347056/convert-iformfilecollection-to-listiformfile-net-core).

Answer (score 0):

[`IFormFileCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfilecollection?view=aspnetcore-6.0) implements
`IEnumerable<IFormFile>`. You can change your property to:

```cs
public IFormFileCollection? imge1 { get; set; }
```

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

> When uploading files using model binding and `IFormFile`, the action
> method can accept:
>
> - A single `IFormFile`.
> - Any of the following collections that represent several files:
>
>   - `IFormFileCollection`
>   - `IEnumerable<IFormFile>`
>   - `List<IFormFile>`